# MVC identity with jquery JSON call

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a Controller:

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DCMGraph(int id = 0){
           return Json("success!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
     }
}
```

When users log in the call goes to index and displays a page with a button which calls  DCMGraph via jquery and displays the result.

If user is not logged-in when accessing the index page it will forward the user to login

But if user leaves the page for sometime the application login times out , and clicks the button to access DCMGraph it generated an error in the background and will not redirect the user to login unless the user refreshes the page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different ways to handle this. The way I am currently handling this scenario would be:

1. make request
2. get response
3. analyze response
4. display data or redirect

The critical step for you would be step 3 where you analyze the response to decide whether to display the data for the chart or redirect to login. Here you can check for an actual JSON feed, an array, length, http status - whatever you need to determine if it's a good request.

With that you should be able to implement a working solution.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping not to put the redirect in script

Comment: Not sure what else you could with the exception of having the page timeout and redirect automatically (like banks do after idling)

Comment: You could return an object with a redirectURL property and if it's not empty redirect to it - less code in javascript - something like 
if (json.redirectURL ){ location.href = json.redirectURL }